# Admin meta Image Path

Tags: custom-field, admin, metabox

```
\inc\admin\inc\images
```

In the admin, images are kept in the above path. say: `image_1.png`

I have to call these images in the Wordpress Post admin in the "**Edit**" mode.

what is the correct method to include image source?

**I am trying to fix it like this →**

```
'img1' => '<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/inc/admin/images/layout.png" alt="Image 1" title="Image 1">'
```

but not working

Comment: Is that the path as it is from the root of your URL?  E.g. `https://myurl.com/inc/admin/inc/admin/image_1.png`

Comment: So, if you were to access through the URL, it'd be `https://myurl.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme/inc/admin/inc/images/image_1.png`?

Comment: Where are you inserting the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your question is still unclear after all the explanations, but based on your efforts, I guess you need to pass the image's URL to a meta field or some sort of array.

So, turning your current code into this will fix the issue:

```
'img1' => '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/admin/images/layout.png" alt="Image 1" title="Image 1">'
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if your question is, how to include these images in a content area wysiwyg, then  the answer is as simple as:

`https://myurl.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme/inc/admin/inc‌​/images/image_1.png`

When WP injects images from the media gallery, it uses the full URL, because the WYSIWYG doesn't process PHP prior to load, so the full URL is injected, which would be the same treatment I'd give this unless there are other unmentioned parameters to your situation.

Comment: You didn't get the question even after explaining you so much; if that would have been the case then there wouldn't be any reason to post this question.